# extraer dato de una lista c#

Tags: c#

Hola espero puedan ayudarme tengo una list y quiero tomar los datos que devuelve pero solo se como llamar a los datos de la lista con un foreach quiero extrae los dato  p.clienterut p.clienteid pero si lo hago en un foreach solo puedo usar las variables dentro del foreach como puedo hacer para extraer una variable de una lista porfa ayuda

````
 List<BuscarClienteViewModels> BuscarCliente = mibds.BuscarCliente(cadena);
               
                                       
                        foreach (var p in BuscarCliente)
                        {
                           
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SECCIÓN" + p.ClienteRut);
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SECCION" + p.ClienteId);                           
                        }

                 EXTRAER DATO FUERA

          ```
````

Comment: Crea las variables al inicio del programa. Saludos

Comment: @ivan muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que necesitas es extraer solo eso dos campos, puedes crear una nueva clase con los campos que necesitas

```
public class NewClass
    {
        public <ElTipo> ClienteRut {get; set;}
        public <ElTipo> ClienteId {get; set;}
    }
```

antes de ejecutar el foreach, crea un instancia del objecto de tipo lista:

```
List<NewClass> newObject = new List<NewClass>();
            foreach (var p in BuscarCliente)
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SECCIÓN" + p.ClienteRut);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SECCION" + p.ClienteId);
                newObject.Add(new NewClass
                {
                    ClienteRut = p.ClienteRut,
                    ClienteId = p.ClienteId,
                });
            }
```